# awk field separator \[ \]

Tags: awk

Given following command:

```
cat 11 | awk -F"[\[\]]" '{print $1,$2}'        
cat 11 | awk -F"[\]\[]" '{print $1,$2}'
```

why does awk output diffrent:

```
zxscgdb@linux:~/tmp> cat 11    
12-05 09:07:53:33 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.    
12-05 09:08:03:35 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.    
12-05 09:08:13:37 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.

zxscgdb@linux:~/tmp> cat 11 | awk -F"[\]\[]" '{print $1,$2}'    
awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'    
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['    
12-05 09:07:53:33 F zxinit_lib.c    
12-05 09:08:03:35 F zxinit_lib.c    
12-05 09:08:13:37 F zxinit_lib.c    

zxscgdb@linux:~/tmp> cat 11 | awk -F"[\[\]]" '{print $1,$2}'    
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['    
awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'    
12-05 09:07:53:33 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.     
12-05 09:08:03:35 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.     
12-05 09:08:13:37 F[zxinit_lib.c] L[485] E[10106] process:zxsc_gdb is ok.
```

Comment: please edit your post to include your expected output. Or indicate what is wrong with each output block. For my understanding of your problem the first result block looks ok. Good luck.

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using? I'm getting the same output as your `cat 11 | awk -F"[\]\[]" '{print $1,$2}'` with both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to use `[` and `]` as delimiter.  In this case:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $1,$2}' 11
```

The char `]` immediately after a `[` (as in `[]]`) is taken as itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bypass shell interpretation using single quotes:

```
awk -F'[\\[\\]]' '{print $2,$4}' 11
```

or escape the first backspace:

```
 awk -F"[\\\[\\\]]" '{print $2,$4}' 11
```

Comment: what do you get when testing? any warnings?

Comment: now it work, i increct input :awk -F"[\\[\\]]" '{print $2,$4}' 11

Comment: No, the above is wrong, you do not need to escape [ and ] at all. See the answer by @jfgagne.