# Extracting a word from the middle of a sentence

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a log file like this:

```
    2013-07-10 21:40:54 [INFO] Janus_Mesca joined the game
    2013-07-10 21:40:54 [INFO] Fenlig joined the game
    2013-07-10 21:41:21 [INFO] BigRedHoodie joined the game
```

I'm trying to print whatever appears in between "[INFO]" and "joined".

With my attempts I've only been able to remove the two words themselves.

```
    tail -500 $rfile | grep "INFO.*joined the game" | \
        sed -e 's/\[INFO\]\(.*\)joined/\1/'
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure grep version with lookahead/lookbehind.
P.S. Option -P might not be available everywhere, but I thought it was clever.

```
tail test.log | grep -Po '(?<=\[INFO\] ).*(?= joined .*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  You just need to make the pattern match the *entire* line, and replace it with the name you've captured.

You can also eliminate the need for `grep` by using a lesser-known feature of `sed`:   Use the `-n` flag to prevent it from printing each line by default, and add a `p` command to make it print the matching lines:

```
tail -n 500 $rfile | sed -n 's/.*INFO] \(.*\)joined .*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an awk answer:

```
awk -F" " '{print $4}' data
```

where data is the input file.  Provided the delimiter is a space, the output is like:

```
Janus_Mesca
Fenlig
BigRedHoodie
```

---

If you want to stick more strictly to the between [INFO] and joined here's an alternative:

```
awk -F"\\[INFO\\] " '{ split( $2, arr, " joined" ); print arr[1] }' data
```

for which I had to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035189/awk-field-separator) to find out how to escape the square brackets.  If you want the leading and trailing spaces left in the user name, take them out of each respective pattern.